# Call ons-back-button by a function

Tags: onsen-ui, monaca

I'm new in Onsen UI. How should I use the 'go-back'-method to go back to the main page? (Like the left back button.) I've tried to do this with pushPage-Method. It works, but the animation is different.

**HTML of the Template with the back / save-Button**

```
<ons-navigator var="profileNavigator">
<ons-list ng-repeat="item in profileData">
<ons-list-item modifier="chevron" class="profile-list-item-container" ng-click="openAboutMeDesc(item.aboutMe)">
      <div class="profile-list-item-left">
        <i class="fa fa-child fa-profile-list"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="profile-list-item-right">
        <div class="profile-list-item-content">
          <div class="profile-category">Über mich
          </div>

          <span class="profile-desc">{{item.aboutMe}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ons-list-item>

<ons-template id="profile-aboutme-desc.html">
<ons-page>
      <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="left">
        <ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
        <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="saveAboutMeDesc(item.naboutMe)">Save</ons-toolbar-button></div>
        <div class="center">About</div>
      </ons-toolbar>
      <ons-row>
      <!--my content-->           
      </ons-row>    
</ons-page>     
</ons-template>
</ons-navigator>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$scope.openAboutMeDesc = function (aboutMe) {
            profileNavigator.pushPage('profile-aboutme-desc.html', { animation : 'slide' } );
        }; 

$scope.saveAboutMeDesc = function (naboutMe) {

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animation is different (forward instead of backward) because, using `profileNavigator.pushPage` method, you are adding a new page to the stack instead of going back to an old one. If you need to go to the main page, consider using `profileNavigator.resetToPage` method.

```
$scope.openAboutMeDesc = function (aboutMe) {
  profileNavigator.resetToPage('profile-aboutme-desc.html', { animation : 'slide' } );
};
```

Remember that you can select the transaction animation between  "slide", "simpleslide", "lift", "fade" and "none".

Take a look at the official documentation if there is something not clear:

https://onsen.io/reference/ons-navigator.html

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much. That rocks!